# jQuery CountDown Every 6 Hours

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I currently have a countdown timer that counts down every 24 hours.  I'm trying to change it to every 6 hours but can't seem to get it to work.  Here's what I have so far.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function ShowTimes2() {
  var now = new Date();
  var hrs = 23-now.getHours();
  var mins = 59-now.getMinutes();
  var secs = 59-now.getSeconds();
  var str = '';
      str += '<b><span style="color:#FFFFFF;font-family:Trebuchet MS,arial;font-size:26px;line-height:50px;">'+hrs+' Hours '+mins+' Minutes '+secs+' Seconds</span></b>';
  document.getElementById('countdownToMidnight2').innerHTML = str;
}
var _cntDown;
function StopTimes() {
    clearInterval(_cntDown);
}

</script>
```

I'm loading it in the body like this:

```
<body id="homepage" onload="_cntDown=setInterval('ShowTimes1()',1000);_cntDown=setInterval('ShowTimes2()',1000)">
```

And then it's included in the body like this:

```
<div id="countdownToMidnight2"></div>
```

Any help would really be appreciated...

Comment: You should describe what it's doing wrong.

Comment: There's nothing wrong happening with the code above.   I'm just trying to change it to every 6 hours instead of every 24 hours...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This only works if it's a constant countdown - when you first initialize your countdown, set a variable for now + 6, and then use that variable instead of 23 in your hours code.

Comment: Do newVar = now.getHours() + 6, and then run newVar - now.getHours() instead of 23 - now.getHours().  Again, this only works if the countdown is only initialized the one time - otherwise, the newVar will always be 6.

Comment: Alright that worked!  When you say "only initialized the one time" do you mean that it won't reset?  It doesn't have to actually reset every 6 hours on the dot, but it should continue to reset about every 6 hours.  Are you saying that it will basically restart after it hits 0 and then someone visits the page?

Comment: No, it means when your countdown starts, it sets the value.  If you refresh the page, then it resets the value and restarts the timer.  If you want a value to always countdown to, you'd need to hard code it or store the initial variable in a cookie so you could read it when the user visits the site.

Comment: Is there no way to add something to the javascript for it to countdown to 0600, 1200, 1800, 2400 - and it counts to whichever comes first at that time?

Comment: Yes, if you have hard values to code in.  For example, make a var like hourNow = now.getHours(), then check that against your hard-coded values (if hourNow < 0600, else if hourNow < 1200, etc), when you find the right one, then set that as the newVar and use it in place of 23 in your original code.  If that makes sense...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43178/discussion-between-user2970202-and-mr-mayers)

Answer (score 0):

Just change

```
var hrs = 23-now.getHours();
```

to

```
var hrs = 5-now.getHours();
```

I think.

Comment: That changed it to showing "-2 Hours 21 Minutes 47 Seconds".  Because when you enter 5 it's actually causing it to down from 5:59 AM every day.